# Regular expression in java for parsing classname from fully qualified name

Tags: java, regex

Can anybody help me in parsing classname from fully qulaified name using regular expression in java.

String to parse like this : "com.xxx.xxx.ClassName 0.0.2

i have to get className using Pattern and Matcher in java

Please help

Comment: Did you try anything? Can we see your approach? Do you have to use regex (if your string is source-code than maybe parser would be better)?

Comment: it is just a version string

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Have you read the javadoc for the Pattern class ... which gives a summary of regex syntax?  If that is too hard to understand, have you looked for a regex tutorial?

Comment: What kind of parsing do you need? Do you want just retrieve string `com.xxx.xxx.ClassName` from source `com.xxx.xxx.ClassName 0.0.2`?

Comment: It would be better if you would post example of actual text you want to parse, expected result and explanation why only such result would be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code which uses positive lookahead in the pattern,

```
String s = "com.xxx.xxx.ClassName 0.0.2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?= )");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/OEtpOj)

**OR**

you could try the below regex which uses lookahead and lookbehind,

```
"(?<=\\.)[^.]*(?= )"
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oujrPu)

Comment: Thanks Avinash, it works.. Thanks to all who helped me